# How I force [count]<C-x> to leave leading zeros?

Tags: visual-block, number-formatting

### Context

I use `vifm` as my file manager (that's off topic here, i know, but keep reading) which allows me to edit filenames inside a `vim` buffer.

One issue i found myself annoyed at are numbered files where I want to keep leading zeros (e.g. `movie0001.webm`).  I can't get vim to format them properly.

### The question

I have a `vim` buffer containing:

```
mov70.webm
mov71.webm
mov72.webm
mov73.webm
mov74.webm
mov75.webm
mov76.webm
mov77.webm
mov78.webm
mov79.webm
```

And my cursor starts at the `m` in the first line.  I then do `VG` to mark everything and `69<C-x>` to transform it into:

```
mov1.webm
mov2.webm
mov3.webm
mov4.webm
mov5.webm
mov6.webm
mov7.webm
mov8.webm
mov9.webm
mov10.webm
```

But i would really like to reach this instead:

```
mov01.webm
mov02.webm
mov03.webm
mov04.webm
mov05.webm
mov06.webm
mov07.webm
mov08.webm
mov09.webm
mov10.webm
```

### What i have tried

The problem with numbers with leading zeros is that `vim` will treat them as `octal`, therefore I changed `nrformats` to an empty string:

```
:set nrformats=
```

Yet, that did not help.  I have searched around in `:h nrformats` without finding anything useful.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `:subsitute` + `printf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in two relatively simple steps:

1. Decrement the lines with `ctrl-x`
2. Run a substituion on the changed lines to add the leading zeros: `'[,']s/\d\@<!\d\>/0\0/`

You could turn that into a command/function if you think you'll need to do this often.

Another way is to do as muru mentioned and use `substitute` + `printf`, which can preserve the string length of the replaced digits:

```
'<,'>s/\d\+/\=printf('%0*d', len(submatch(0)), submatch(0) - 69)
```

This could also be turned into a reusable command:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range Decr <line1>,<line2>s/\d\+/\=printf('%0*d', len(submatch(0)), submatch(0) - <args>)
```

Which you can run with `:'<,'>Decr 69` to decrement the visual lines by 69.

Comment: I'm still learning `viscript` but `len(submatch(0))` is a great trick.  Added it to my `vimrc`, and also added a `Incr` command.

Answer (score 8):

While I'd definitely go with `:s` + `printf` for complex replacements, I can get the effect you desire if I start from `00`, and have `set nrformats-=octal`. That is:

1. Select the numbers in a visual block:

   [image]

   Note that I have added `mov76.webm` - you don't actually have ten files in your example list.
2. Replace with zeros and select the same region again: `r0gv`

   [image]
3. Use `g<c-a>`:

   [image]

Without `set nrformats-=octal`, you'll see `010`, `011`, etc.

Comment: Your `0`s look like eyes. Creepy.

Comment: Ooops, that was a mistake with the `mov76.webm`, i used a bad directory.  I edited the question. Yay, for the *andale* font.

Comment: @grochmal That's the Ubuntu Mono font. :D

Comment: @romainl and now I can't unsee it.

Comment: The suggestion to  use `set nrformats-=octal` worked for me! I often need to increment text with leading zeros and always was confused why the behavior was not as expected. As for other number formats (oct, hex, binary), well, I have never needed to increment them using vim.